# How to delete original and duplicate line when matching by column using awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have found a partial answer to my question but I can't figure out the rest. I'm using awk. I can delete original and duplicate lines using the following command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} a[$0]<2' infile infile
```

However this requires the entire line to be duplicated. Does anyone know how to delete the original and duplicate lines when matching by column 1?

I tried this

```
awk 'key[$1]; NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next} a[$0]<2' infile infile
```

but that didn't get me anywhere. I have a file with the following type of data:

```
srv13108 f15001:/export/rack131/srv13108
srv13407 f15001:/export/rack134/srv13407
srv13501 f13901:/export/rack135/srv13501
srv13501 f14001:/export/rack135/srv13501
srv13609 f14901:/export/rack136/srv13609 
srv14407 f14101:/export/rack144/srv14407
```

and I want the output to be:

```
srv13108 f15001:/export/rack131/srv13108
srv13407 f15001:/export/rack134/srv13407
srv13609 f14901:/export/rack136/srv13609
srv14407 f14101:/export/rack144/srv14407
```

As the 2 lines had a matching column 1.

Answer (score 5):

you need awk on-liner?

```
awk '{a[$1]=$0;u[$1]++}END{for(i in u)if(u[i]==1)print a[i]}'  file
```

gives:

```
srv13609 f14901:/export/rack136/srv13609
srv13108 f15001:/export/rack131/srv13108
srv13407 f15001:/export/rack134/srv13407
srv14407 f14101:/export/rack144/srv14407
```

Comment: @Kent I went brain dead on a `awk` solution for this, obvious now  +1.

Comment: @sudo_O actually reading that file twice (like in his question) works too. first time u[$1]++, 2nd time checking if the read $1 is unique, do print.

Comment: 2 pass method would be less efficient however.